# Amazon cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I am using this following pattern to search, using AWS cloudsearch.

"size=#{size}&start=#{start}&rank=-time&bq=(phrase+field%3dtitle+#{title})"

But, i got following error in my log file.

{"error"=>"info", "rid"=>"e2467862eecf73ecde7f57355cd6db92c97fad04398ce82b1f57903fa3c9b6fe81d4b1abf5036425", "time-ms"=>0, "cpu-time-ms"=>4, "messages"=>[{"severity"=>"fatal", "code"=>"CS-InvalidMatchSetExpression", "message"=>"[WARNING] Syntax error in match set expression: unexpected '=' character"}]

Give me an suggestion. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you log the querystring of the request that is being sent to CloudSearch?  Also note that `bq` is now `fq` if you're using the latest CloudSearch. And `%3d` is an encoded `=`, but that seems like the correct syntax for a phrase search anyway.

Comment: Yeah!, thanks all. it is my mistake, i used 2011API, but i refer 2013 API . so i get confused to use term, phrase , range. now i am cleared.